# Proper way to access usersinfo using mongodb driver for .net/c#

Tags: c#, mongodb

When I write this line of code (C# using mongodb driver):

```
var mongoDB = ...
var result = mongoDB.FindUser("ruprecht");
```

I get a warning that I should "Use the new user management command "usersinfo".
But I can find no example of how to do this.

I'll just use the deprecated commands for now, but I'd like to know the right way to do it.

Answer (score 1):

*I realize this thread is a couple years old, but this is a question I've been looking for an answer to for quite some time with great difficulty, so I figured I'd answer for the sake of future Googlers.*

## Your Code:

Your attempts were close, but not quite the syntax RunCommand is looking for. If you take a look at the Reference page (https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/command/usersInfo/), the syntax for the Mongo Shell looks like this:

#### Mongo Shell Code:

```
{ usersInfo: { user: <name>, db: <db> },
  showCredentials: <Boolean>,
  showPrivileges: <Boolean>
}
```

When we translate that to C#, it's a bit more complex, but it'll look something like this.

#### C# Code:

```
command = new CommandDocument
    {
        {"usersInfo", new BsonDocument
            {
                {"user", "reprecht"},
                {"db", "myDatabaseName"}
            }
        }
    };
myOpenDb.RunCommand (command)
```

Note the `new BsonDocument` part in there. That's generally what you'll need to do in cases of nested brackets.

## Another Example:

For the sake of completeness, let's look at another example say you wanted to add a new user. The documentation [here](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/command/createUser/) shows it like this:

#### Mongo Shell Code:

```
{ createUser: "<name>",
  pwd: "<cleartext password>",
  customData: { <any information> },
  roles: [
    { role: "<role>", db: "<database>" } | "<role>",
    ...
  ],
  writeConcern: { <write concern> }
}
```

So, ignoring the optional customData and writeConcern, we can write this in C# like this:

#### C# Code:

```
command = new CommandDocument
{
    {"createUser", "myUser"},
    {"pwd", "myPassword"},
    {"roles", new BsonArray 
        {
            new BsonDocument
            {
                {"role", "readWrite"},
                {"db", "myDatabaseName"}
            }
        }
    }
};
```

Again, note that we used `new BsonArray` to create an array like in the shell code.

Hopefully, that gives you a good place to start. You should be able to execute any command in this manner, though this is more of a guess/hope on my part than something I've extensively tested.

Comment: This answer certainly helped me as a future Googler :)  This is a clear and concise answer that worked well when I used the above code as a template.

Answer (score 0):

You use the MongoDatabase's RunCommand method and the usersInfo command documented here: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/command/usersInfo/#dbcmd.usersInfo.

Comment: So I tried this:  `result = myOpenDb.RunCommand("{usersInfo: 'reprecht'}");` and I just get a **'no such cmd'** error.

Comment: This: `var result = myOpenDb.RunCommand(new CommandDocument("usersInfo", "ruprecht"));` fails with the same error.